# Hash won't save in user_meta

Tags: wordpress

If I run `var_dump($localkeydata);` I get this output...

> string(854) "==QfigjMyATOxAjMiojIlRXYkt2Ylh2YiwiI1ImN1UTN3MGOjRTN1QWN3EDMjJmYhdzM2UWOmFzMiRmI 6ICazFGa1QWbiwiIBBVQD9lSH9CXz5WanVHbw9CX05WZ052bj1Cc39CXhBXYj9CXt92YuMnbvlGd1x2b zRXZuJXZ05WaqdmLz52bpRXds92cvwlan9CXl12bo9CXiojI5J3b0NWZylGZklGbhZnIsIyNy4yN44SN 4EjLykTMiojIwlGZpxWY2JCLi02bj5ycu9Wa0VHbvNHdl5mclRnbpp2ZuMnbvlGd1x2bz5yd3dHLt92Y uMnbvlGd1x2bzRXZuJXZ05WaqdmLz52bpRXds92ciojIulWYt9GZklGbhZnIsICduV3bjNWQgUWZyZkI 6ISZsNWejdmbpxGbpJmIsICMw0CMw0CMwADMiojIlRXYkVWdkRHel5mIsICMwoDMwoDMwAiNy0iMw0SO xAjMiojIlRXYkdWZyJCLiwWYpJHVgUWZyZEIBBVQDBiSHJiOiUWbh5GdjVHZvJHciwiI2cDMwEjI6ICZ pR3Y1R2byBnIsIiNxQTMiojIklWZjlmdyV2ciwiIt92YuMnbvlGd1x2bTRXZuJXZ05WaKdEQulWbkFmI 6ICbpFWblJCLiMnbvlGd1x2bTBCdl5mclRnbJBiSHJiOiUWbh5WeuFGct92YiwiIy9GdhJHdzlmbp1GZ BBSblR3c5NlI6ISZtFmbkVmclR3cpdWZyJCLiUmdpR3YBJiOiMXd0FGdzJyef8b393f4ba17412543a8 9c6ba48b933d241867cef6acbf8d9c6fecb1733338b3"

If I then run this command...

`update_user_meta( $current_user->ID,'GJ_CAPA_Site_localkey',$localkeydata);`

...the command says it is successful; however, when I look at the mySQL table, the `meta_key` field is added; however, the value of `meta_value` is NULL.

Why?

I need to be able to save the hash. As part of a different function altogether, I was able to successfully save the hash using the `update_option()` and `add_option()` commands. It seams that it works for `update_option()` and `add_option()` but not `update_user_meta()`

## UPDATE

Worth noting that I can successfully add anything else but there is something about the hash value in `$localkeydata` that just won't be accepted. I am pretty sure it relates to the carriage returns.

Answer (score 0):

It works check using

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();

update_user_meta( $user->ID,'GJ_CAPA_Site_localkey',$localkeydata);

echo get_user_meta( $user->ID,'GJ_CAPA_Site_localkey',true);
```

I am getting the data in table 
[image]

Comment: Very weird... I ran your code and it appears to work, but when I go check the table, the data is not actually there.... I even put a `die()` command right after your code to ensure nothing else happened after. If I do this first `$localkeydata = str_replace("\n","<br>",$localkeydata);` I have no issues. I can save anything as long as it doesn't have `\n`.  Try running the code... let it say it worked. Then run just your check code and see if it still says it worked.

Comment: If its the case your variable $localkeydata is not getting properly initialised thats why value is not in database or one more reason can be that mysql errors please check for errorlog